# How to view Navionics bathymetry Web API in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, web-service, bathymetry

I am looking to view a Navionics bathymetry map in QGIS. The maps can viewed in a browser on the Navionics website here: https://webapp.navionics.com/?lang=en#boating@6&key=%7B%7DoiGbyvcN

Is it possible to import this as a layer into QGIS? Similar to how the openlayers plugin imports background data. I've tried navigating the 'QGIS Web Connector' with little success. The [Navionics Web API](http://webapiv2.navionics.com/) is based on OpenLayers 3.0 so I suspect this should be possible.

Comment: I suspect the answer will be `theoretically possible`, you'll need to write your own plugin or extend the OpenLayers plugin.  The maps aren't being presented in any obvious standard way, so you won't be able to use any standard interfaces.